# 2005 V-8 4 runner 72,000 SE

Tags: toyota, battery, 4runner

I've stored my 4Runner and not in extreme weather but it has a slow start how long does a heavy duty battery last without replacing it. Had the problem last winter drove a hundred miles or so stopped got back in, dead... just to find the cables were corroded. How often should I replace this battery for this vehicle it's had 2 batteries since I've owned it. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

If the vehicle sits for a long time without being started, the battery itself will lose charge over time. Something like 5% of the stored energy will be lost per month, but this doesn't mean the battery will be dead or beyond recharging. It just means it may need a jump start when you go to start it for the first time after it's been in storage for a period of time. Batteries usually last for about five years as long as they aren't abused too badly.

Consider either placing a battery tender on the battery while it's being stored and/or disconnecting the battery from the vehicle as well. This will help the battery keep its charge for a longer time.

Comment: Battery tenders and battery minders do nothing but slowly discharge the battery. If you only drive it a couple times a year, disconnect the battery and keep it on a 2 amp smart charger. Your best bet is to avoid a conventional charger because you risk overcharging and destroying the battery. With a smart charger, you can leave it on and the charger will sense the voltage drop, charge, and stop when it reaches full charge. If the cables are corroded, replace them as they will create a draw.

Comment: @AlexVolpe - Not sure where you got your information from, but [battery tenders](http://www.batterytender.com/) maintain your battery, not deplete them. They are typically known as "smart chargers" because that exactly how they behave. A trickle charger which is a mode comes on a standard battery charger will cause the issues you're talking about.